# django model translation - returning the wrong language content

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

I am using this [model-translation package](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)

everything works fine now in admin, i created an object in admin with english content. and my page is actually in german. .. e.g. starts with `/de/blabla/`.

then I opened the page which should render all items from db of a model. in my views i did

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language
print get_language()
bloglists = models.BlogList.objects.filter()
```

I am getting `de` for `get_language()` and the query is giving me still the english content.

but the docs say:

> Assuming the current language is de in the news example from above,
>   the translated title field will return the value from the title_de
>   field:

```
# Assuming the current language is "de"
n = News.objects.all()[0]
t = n.title  # returns german translation

# Assuming the current language is "en"
t = n.title  # returns english translation
```

but why not working for me? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok never mind. the solution was:

I had to first create an entry in default language and then create the other translations. and then the "rendering the right language content" works.

cool stuff.